# Is atomic<T*> always lock free?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdatomic

On my MAC OS, `atomic<T*>` is lock free.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::atomic<void*>().is_lock_free() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

output: 1
```

I want to know if `atomic<T*>` is always lock free?

Is there a reference to introduce it?

Comment: From [std::atomic::is_lock_free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free): *"Notes

All atomic types except for std::atomic_flag may be implemented using mutexes or other locking operations, rather than using the lock-free atomic CPU instructions."*

Comment: It isn't guaranteed by the standard, check whenever in doubt.

Comment: @Jarod42: That sounds like an answer; not a comment. (Like Ville-Valterri posted)

Comment: On macOS you can count on an x86_64 processor, so yes.  Finding one that isn't is pretty difficult shopping btw, probably requires a trip to the museum.  It won't have a C++11 compiler.

Comment: I know a member function pointer isn't usually what one would think of when you read `T*` (neither does template argument deduction think that), but I know member function pointers can be larger than `sizeof(void*)` on modern Windows platforms, so I doubt these will qualify as lock free at all. Just to say: a pointer isn't always a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The standard allows implementing any atomic type (with exception of std::atomic_flag) to be implemented with locks.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free) Even if the platform would allow lock-free atomics for some type, the standard library developers might not have implemented that.

If you need to implement something differently when locks are used, this can be checked at compile time using `ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE` macro.

Comment: You can also use `if constexpr(std::atomic_is_lock_free(&obj))`; the `ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE macro` is for compatibility with C11.

Comment: In practice, all mainstream C++ implementations for normal modern CPUs have `always_lock_free` atomics for any object the width of 1 pointer.  (Or they're an 8-bit single-core microcontroller or something).  So if you did something like `static_assert( std::atomic<T *>::is_always_lock_free, "this code will be slow without lock-free atomics");` you won't actually be missing out on any important portability. (For code that's already using C++11 `std::atomic` and `std::thread` features.)  The guarantee that only `atomic_flag` must be lock_free is mostly only interesting for retrocomputing.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe to assume that any particular platform's implementation of `std::atomic` is always lock free.

The standard specifies some marker macros, including [`ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE`](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.lockfree), which indicates either pointers are never, sometimes or always lock free, for the platform in question.

You can also get an answer from `std::atomic<T *>::is_always_lock_free`, for your particular `T`.<sup>1</sup>

Note 1: A given pointer type [must be consistent](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.lockfree#2), so the instance method `std::atomic<T *>::is_lock_free()` is redundant.